# Issue to Create Survey Invitation Link on Salesforce

Tags: salesforce-survey

We are encountering difficulties in creating the survey invitation link for our participants. Is there any way to generate the link without sending an email or without having to manually click on "Get Survey Invitation," select the survey, and generate the invitation link? Our participants do not have email IDs, and we require the link to be automatically generated. Could you please provide guidance on how this can be accomplished?

Thank you.

Comment: Is creating the `SurveyInvitation` record via a Flow an option for you? That is what we do; once that record is created it contains a field with the link to the SurveyInvitation, suitable for use in an email. This (2018) [example](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/send-salesforce-survey-without-writing-code/) shows how to do this (using the older Flow UX)

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Cropredy. However, we don't need to use Flow or custom automation. Is there any standard functionality available for generating the link? Please advise.

Comment: The SurveyInvitation Link depends on the existence of a SurveyInvitation record